# Issue loading custom font

Tags: java, fonts, stream, embedded-resource, ioexception

I am attempting to load a font, in slick2d, which (in eclipse) is located at: `"resources\fonts\slkscr.ttf"` with the following code:

```
private void loadResources()  {
    try  {
        Font fontRaw = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
            new BufferedInputStream(Game.class.getClassLoader().
                getResourceAsStream("resources/fonts/slkscr.ttf")));
        Font fontBase = fontRaw.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);

        this.font = new TrueTypeFont(fontBase, false);
    } catch (IOException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The stack trace prints:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:151) 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) 
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) 
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:885) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.EditorState.loadResources(EditorState.java:43) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.EditorState.init(EditorState.java:61) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:36) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.Game.main(Game.java:31) java.io.IOException: Stream closed 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:151) 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) 
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) 
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) 
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:885) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.EditorState.loadResources(EditorState.java:43) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.EditorState.init(EditorState.java:61) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:171) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390) 
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314) 
    at org.darestium.applications.games.game.Game.main(Game.java:31) 
Mon Jun 04 18:36:32 EST 2012 ERROR:null
```

Any ideas regarding how I could prevent the font from not loading?

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like you have an IOException inside another IOException, maybe a threading/concurrency problem in your game loop? (just guessing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void loadResources() throws FontFormatException, IOException  {
        Font fontRaw = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("resources/fonts/slkscr.ttf"));
        Font fontBase = fontRaw.deriveFont(28f);
        this.font = new TrueTypeFont(fontBase, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a leading slash to indicate to search from the root of the class-path, vis.

```
..getResourceAsStream("/resources/fonts/slkscr.ttf")..
```

---

As an aside.  That `stream closed` message might be telling us that `createFont` requires a repositionable `InputStream`.  Try instead:

```
getResource("/resources/fonts/slkscr.ttf")
```

..or..

```
getResource("/slkscr.ttf")
```

..depending upon path.

Comment: Sadly, that did not seem to fix the issue :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, also, I just just put the font in the project root and use the following line: [code]getResourceAsStream("slkscr.ttf")[/code] I still get a exception thrown.

Comment: What happens if you use: `getResourceAsStream("/slkscr.ttf")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the font all wrong, you should look at the examples here [Slick Wiki - True Type Fonts](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=truetype_font_support)

Comment: Yes, that is how I was loading the fonts originally... (custom fonts)

Comment: YOUR LINK IS NOT WORKING..:)