# Using Custom Fonts [java.io.IOException: Error reading font data.]

Tags: java, text, fonts

The title doesn't allow me to say Problem, so the actual error message was -

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
at AddFont.createFont(AddFont.java:11)
at MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:105)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code is -

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
    try {
        AddFont addFont = new AddFont();
        addFont.createFont();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    createGUI();

 } //public void run() Closing
});
}
```

and the file that I used to get the AddFont addFont-

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class AddFont extends MainFrame{
public void createFont(){
Font ttfBase = null;
    Font telegraficoFont = null;{
try {
    InputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO));
    ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
    telegraficoFont = ttfBase.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("Font not loaded.");
}
}
}
}
```

I was instructed to make a new thread because this is a separate problem from my other one.

Why am I getting this problem, and how can I fix it? 
I have my TELEGRAFICO.TTF font in my imageFolder, which is really just my resources folder. I use

```
   public static final String FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO = "imageFolder/TELEGRAFICO.TTF";
```

to call in my path.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - I no longer get that error message, and I don't get "Font not loaded". How can I use the font in other class files other than the one I made that method in?

(I want to use that font on buttons in multiple class files. I tried using it here -

```
regButton = new JButton();
regButton.setText("Foo");
regButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
regButton.setFont(telegraficoFont);
```

But it said telegraficoFont cannot be resolved to a variable. (Because it was in a different class file.)

How can I fix this? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Instead of `AddFont.class.getResourceAsStream(FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO)` try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO)`.

Comment: @Perception okay, so what do I do about the second part, which is 

Font telegraficoFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,telegraficoFontAdd);

That code removes the variable telegraficoFontAdd.

Comment: Use the full package path to access the font, for example /com/mydomain/imageFolder/TELEGRAFICO.TTF.

Comment: please post full error stack trace.

Comment: @Ravi Trivedi, Full error edited into the message.

Comment: I think you have problem finding the font file or stream problem. Check out these answers >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10895492/2093375 **AND** http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2268351&postcount=2

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I edited my main post, please take a look. Almost there!

Comment: @Hathor, Define `telegraficoFont` as Object field. Then use `Getter` & `Setter` to access the variable in any class after creating new object. It is at the moment defined in a method, so it has only local scope.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I'm not familiar with the Getter / Setter, so I'll look into that. You should probably add your answer as an answer to this question, so if it works, I can accept it, and mark this question as complete.

Comment: @Hathor, cool ! check out the answer. It's easy and flexible. No need of Getter/Setter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have a problem with possible `font file locating` and `font stream creation`,

**Try this** >> [Issue loading custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894426/issue-loading-custom-font/10895492#10895492) **AND** http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2268351&postcount=2

**To answer your question `"how to make this function easy to use everywhere"`, do as this:**

```
    public class AddFont extends MainFrame {

    private static Font ttfBase = null;
    private static Font telegraficoFont = null;
    private static InputStream myStream = null;
    private static final String FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO = "imageFolder/TELEGRAFICO.TTF";

    public Font createFont() {


            try {
                myStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(FONT_PATH_TELEGRAFICO));
                ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
                telegraficoFont = ttfBase.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24);               
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Font not loaded.");
            }
            return telegraficoFont;
    }
}
```

**And then in your calling class:**

```
    public class Test {

    public static Font font = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (font == null) {
                        font = AddFont.createFont();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                createGUI();

            } // public void run() Closing
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this out, had to make a few edits to work in my project files, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In some cases the cause is the running instance not being able to write to the Java temp directory (java.io.tmpdir).

If your are running it on tomcat maybe you deleted the temp directory of the tomcat installation, or the folder have wrong permissions.

(tomcat folder)/temp

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, maybe the [Fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) is lack in your running environment. After installing, everything is OK.

For example,

```
yum install fontconfig
```

Comment: This was the issue for me (on a minimal CI machine)

Comment: solved the issue for me too, in ubuntu 16. thanks

Comment: Solved issue for me on minimal docker container

Answer (score 0):

you could try to install "dejavu-sans-fonts" and fontconfig, it works